# Get __definesetter__ original function

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the code below to block cookies from being stored.

```
document.__defineSetter__('cookie', function () {
  return '';
});
```

How can I access the original setter function, before I override it, so I can store it and restore it later?

Comment: Is [`__lookupSetter__()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__) what you want?

Comment: However, both these methods are obsolete and shouldn't be used.

Comment: This is the modern way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: btw, the setter/getter is defined on `Document.prototype`, not on `document`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```js
let cookie_setter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, "cookie").set;
console.log(cookie_setter);
```

Since this is inherited from `Document.prototype`, you need to specify that in the call.